# Trigger Event when key is pressed and some other condition is true at the same time

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In a non-event-based language this task is done like this:

```
if (keypressed() and other_condition) {
  doSomething();
}
```

I can hardy imagine how to reach the same goal when I don't have conditions but rather eventlisteners.

```
  $(document).on("keypress", function (a) {
    ....
  });

 $(document).on("othercondition", function (a) {
    ....
  });
```

---

To be less general:
I call a function `report`. Within the function body, I want to perform a test, whether a key is currently pressed. This function within shall not be declared newly every time I invoke the report-function.

```
  var report = function(e) {

       if (keypressed()) {
       }
  }
```

Comment: `othercondition` is like what for example, event as well?

Comment: Could you not simply add a `if(other_condition) {}` inside your event handler?

Comment: yes, othercondition is event as well

Comment: I edited the question. Look above.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
var condition1 = false;
var condition2 = false;
$(document).on("keypress", function (a) {
  condition1 = true;
  if(condition1 && condition2) {
    ....
  }
  
});

$(document).on("othercondition", function (a) {
  condition2 = true;
  if(condition1 && condition2) {
    ....
  }
});
```